# PHP preg_replace problem

Tags: php, regex, url

This is a follow-up question to the one [I posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971771/using-preg-replace-to-back-reference-array-key-and-replace-with-a-value) (thanks to [mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345031/mario))

Ok, so I have a preg_replace statement to replace a url string with `sometext`, insert a value from a query string (using `$_GET["size"]`) and insert a value from a associative array (using `$fruitArray["$1"]` back reference.)

Input url string would be:

```
http://mysite.com/script.php?fruit=apple
```

Output string should be:

```
http://mysite.com/small/sometext/green/
```

The PHP I have is as follows:

```
$result = preg_replace('|http://www.mysite.com/script.php\?fruit=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)|e', ' "http://www.mysite.com/" .$_GET["size"]. "/sometext/" .$fruitArray["$1"]. "/"', $result);
```

This codes outputs the following string:

```
 http://mysite.com/small/sometext//
```

The code seems to skip the value in `$fruitArray["$1"]`.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: When asking such a question, you should entirely remove the $_GET and $fruitArray and use constants instead, to localize the problem to the preg_replace only. Maybe your variables are empty, we can't know it for sure

Comment: @Riccardo Galli You are quite correct there, lesson learnt - must stop writing php on the back of a fag packet and move to a PHP IDE - do you have any recommendations? I'm such a noob :/ Cheers.

Comment: Managed to solve this by re-writing some of the preceding code; I had other preg_replace calls interfering with the url string :/ Perhaps my code above was semi-OK after all :-) This project started small but now its hundreds and hundreds of lines of code - Apologies to all - I do  appreciate the answers though, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, weird thing.

Your code work's perfectly fine for me (see below code that I used for testing locally).

I did however fix 2 things with your regex:

1. Don't use | as a delimiter, it has meaning in regex.
2. Your regular expression is only giving the illusion that it works as you're not escaping the `.`s. It would actually match `http://www#mysite%com/script*php?fruit=apple` too.

Test script:

```
$fruitArray = array('apple' => 'green');
$_GET = array('size' => 'small');
$result = 'http://www.mysite.com/script.php?fruit=apple';
$result = preg_replace('@http://www\.mysite\.com/script\.php\?fruit=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)@e', ' "http://www.mysite.com/" .$_GET["size"]. "/sometext/" .$fruitArray["$1"]. "/"', $result);
echo $result;
```

Output:

```
Rudis-Mac-Pro:~ rudi$ php tmp.php
http://www.mysite.com/small/sometext/green/
```

The only thing this leads me to think is that `$fruitArray` is not setup correctly for you.

---

By the way, I think this may be more appropriate, as it will give you more flexibility in the future, better syntax highlighting and make more sense than using the `e` modifier for the `evil()` function to be internally called by PHP ;-) It's also a lot cleaner to read, IMO.

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('@http://www\.mysite\.com/script\.php\?fruit=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]*)@', function($matches) {
        global $fruitArray;
        return 'http://www.mysite.com/' . $_GET['size'] . '/sometext/' . $fruitArray[$matches[1]] . '/';
}, $result);
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and for pointing out better ways of doing this; it's appreciated. I'm off to have a go at preg_replace_callback, something new for me, cheers :)

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help, also relieved to hear it wasn't this code you posted as it was confusing me that it would work for me and not you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

i write it again, i don't understand good where is the error, the evaluation of preg results is very weird in php

```
preg_replace(
    '|http\://([\w\.-]+?)/script\.php\?fruit=([\w_-]+)|e'
    , '"http://www.$1/".$_GET["size"]."/sometext/".$fruitArray["$2"]."/";'
    , $result
);
```

Comment: thanks for your effort, I managed to resolve this now though. regex is so powerful yet so hard to master :/ Cheers!

Comment: @Matt regexp are powerful as you say, but sometimes is hard to be human readable even if you write it, and is a good practice write it again. 

Regexps are just practice... keep in that way a regexp question is always a nifty question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have forgotten to escape the `?`.  It should be `/script.php\?`, with a `\?` to escape properly, as in the linked answer you provided.

Comment: whoops, I just forgot to do that in the example posted here; the actual code is escaped properly. Code updated, thanks for pointing it out - problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

$fruitArray["\$1"] instead of $fruitArray["$1"]